# Eclipse fail to build and run the android App

Tags: android, eclipse, build

When first I use to run android project in automatically upload the apk file and run it. It worked for a week. Now when I run a project , the console inform me that the .apk is uploaded and installed but when I run the app. in android emulator , its not the updated one. Any ideas why Eclipse giving this issue ..

Comment: according to your point what is console?

Comment: By Console I mean the Eclipse IDE console ...

Comment: first improve your asking technique. exactly what have to trying to convey.i cant able to understand.if make image in your mind and ask question proper manner.it is better to asking a question with use image or step by step question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clean a project (Project->Clean) or Try to uninstall App from emulator.

Answer (score 0):

or try to uninstall app from your emulator:
settings->applications->manage applications->(your app)->uninstall